# Core Data in Swift: Comparing objects in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, core-data

I'm trying to update the user's music listen history by checking to see if any `MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount`s have changed since the last check. Right now, upon each check, I'm querying the entire iPod library and comparing their existing play counts already in Core Data. If current play count != play count stored in Core Data, we do something with that song, since we know the user has listened to it recently.

In my code, **I'm struggling to loop through all iPod songs *and* search for corresponding Core Data objects simultaneously.** The code below prints out way too many lines. How do I search for objects in Core Data in a `for` loop?

```
class func checkiPodSongsForUpdate() {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "IPodSongs")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)


        let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

        let queryResult = query.collections as! [MPMediaItemCollection]

        for song in queryResult {

            for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {

                request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", "\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))")

                for result: AnyObject in results! {

                    if let playCount = result.valueForKey("playCount") as? String {

                        if playCount != "\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount))" {

                            println("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)) has a new play count.")

                        } else {

                            println("User hasn't listened to this song since last check.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution. Looping through two arrays can get expensive with enough objects in each array, just as @Tom said. I decided to loop through `arrayOne` and inside that loop, call a custom function that looks for the given key/value pair in `arrayTwo`.

```
// Custom function that returns Bool if arrayTwo contains a given key/value pair from inside the arrayOne loop

        func arrayContains(array:[[String:String]], #key: String, #value: String) -> Bool {
            for song in array {
                if song[key] == value {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
```

Big thanks to @vacawama for the help here: [Find key-value pair in an array of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418101/find-key-value-pair-in-an-array-of-dictionaries/30418562?noredirect=1#comment48924623_30418562)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you assign a value to `request.predicate`, but doing so has no effect. A fetch request predicate only has effect if you assign it *before* doing the fetch. It becomes part of the fetch, and the fetch results only include objects that match the predicate.

There are a couple of possibilities for fixing this specific problem:

1. Do your Core Data fetch in the loop *after* assigning the predicate, inside the loop. This would get the results you expect. However it will also be **extremely** inefficient and won't scale well. Fetch requests are relatively expensive operations, so you'll probably find that you're spending a lot of time doing them.
2. Instead of assigning a value to `request.predicate`, filter the `results` array in memory by doing something like

   ```
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", "\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))")
   let currentResults = results.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
   ```

   That will get you an array of only the songs matching the predicate. This will be faster than option #1, but it still leaves the major problem that you're fetching *all* of the songs here. This potentially means loading a ton of managed objects into memory every time you call this function (suppose the user has, say, 50,000 songs?). It's still not a good solution. Unfortunately I don't know enough about `MPMediaQuery` to recommend a better approach.

Either of these should fix the immediate problem, but you need to address the more significant conceptual issue. You're comparing two potentially large collections looking for a single match. That's going to be a lot of CPU time or memory or both no matter how you approach it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom. But I can't invoke `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` with an argument list of type `NSPredicate`. Your broader idea is to store Core Data search results in a dictionary (I'll have title, artist, & playcount for each song), then loop over that dictionary with the `MPMediaQuery`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about not being able to invoke `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` with an argument that's an `NSPredicate`. That's the only way to call the method. And no, I did not mention using a dictionary as you describe, nor do I recommend it. I do recommend trying to find a better solution than comparing two large collections of objects as you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm removing the `request.predicate` line, replacing it with your suggestion, and am getting that error. Did that actually work for you in Xcode? It of course makes sense to me, just can't figure out why I'm getting that error.