# Find key-value pair in an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, search, dictionary

I have two arrays of dictionaries. I want to iterate through the first array by searching for either 1) the entire dictionary or 2) a key-value pair within a dictionary in the second array.

If I try to search for the entire dictionary, I get error: `Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '(Array<Dictionary<String, String>>, [String : String])'`.

```
for var i = 0; i < arrayOne.count; i++ {

    for item in arrayOne {

        if contains(arrayTwo, arrayOne[i]) == nil {

            // Do something

        }
    } 
}
```

And if I try to search for just a key-value pair within the second array, I get: `Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, String>>' with an index of type 'String'`

```
for item in arrayOne {

     if contains(arrayTwo, arrayOne["title"]) {

         // Do something

     }
}
```

I need to be able to search the second array of dictionaries for some value in the first array of dictionaries. How can I do that?

EDIT: Both arrays have the same declarations:

```
var arrayOne : Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = Array()
var arrayTwo : Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = Array()
```

Comment: Please add the declaration of your two arrays.

Comment: @ThomasKilian see edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works.  You can iterate through the items of each array comparing them to the items in the other:

```
for item1 in arrayOne {
    for item2 in arrayTwo {
        if item1 == item2 {
            println("found a dictionary common to both arrays")
        }
    }
}
```

Searching for common key/value pairs in the two arrays:

```
for dict1 in arrayOne {
    for (key, value) in dict1 {
        for dict2 in arrayTwo {
            if dict2[key] == value {
                println("found \(key):\(value) in both arrays")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you're searching for a particular key:

```
let key = "title"

for dict1 in arrayOne {
    if let value = dict1[key] {
        for dict2 in arrayTwo {
            if dict2[key] == value {
                println("found \(key):\(value) in both arrays")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can write your own `arrayContains` function that takes the types you need:

```
func arrayContains(array:[[String:String]], value:[String:String]) -> Bool {
    for item in array {
        if item == value {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And then use it to find the values you want:

```
// Save all of the dictionaries from the first array that aren't in the second array

var newArray:[[String:String]] = []

for item in arrayOne {
    if !arrayContains(arrayTwo, item) {
        newArray.append(item)
    }
}
```

---

To search the array for a particular key/value pair:

```
func arrayContains(array:[[String:String]], #key: String, #value: String) -> Bool {
    for dict in array {
        if dict[key] == value {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

let result = arrayContains(arrayTwo, key: "title", value: "Alien!")
```

Comment: I need to use a function like `contains()` or `find()` because I need to save each object that isn't in arrayTwo. By looping through both, every item in arrayOne will != an item in arrayTwo, which is not what I want. I need to loop through arrayOne, and actually **search** for the item in arrayTwo. Can I do that by only looping through one array?

Comment: How would I go about searching arrayTwo for a key within a dictionary from arrayOne, as opposed to searching arrayTwo for the entire dictionary?

Comment: Do you want to search for a key, or for a particular key/value pair?  Would you want it to work the same way, the search returns `true` if the `key/value` pair is found and `false` otherwise?

Comment: I want to search for a key/value pair. And yes I'd still like to return a `Bool`.